# PowerShell Python command-line arguments

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, sys

I'm trying to run a Python script in PowerShell. While using `sys` module I stumble upon a problem of getting the return value of a PowerShell function. The function in question is `Date -f 'dd\/MM\/yyyy'` that returns `14/03/2019` and I'd like that value to be used as an argument in the Python script. I've been able so far to get the literal arguments from the command line, e.g. `text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Python script (see [`sys.argv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)):

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

called like this in Powershell:

```
python .\test.py -date $(Date -f "dd\/MM\/yyyy")
```

outputs:

```
['.\\test.py', '-date', '14/03/2019']
```

On a general note, I recommend using better date formats than `dd/MM/yyyy` - ISO 8061 `yyyy-MM-dd` would be a good one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to have the output of the command `Date -f 'dd\/MM\/yyyy'` to be fed into your python script (`script.py`).

What you are looking for are so called "pipes" or output redirects. Looking at the officical documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6) the following might work:

```
$DATE=Date -f 'dd/\MM\/yyyy'
Write-Output $DATE | python script.py
```